# Special \boxed environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

My problem is the following: I have a tikz picture:
[image]

I want those boxes to all have the same height, and I also want them to start completely at the bottom like the box in the top right corner.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to do to this?

Comment: Working code so far?

Comment: those boxes are just simply \boxed{...}. The whole tikz image contains quite some macro's, so posting it would take a long time.

Comment: Adding `\strut` to the content of the boxes might be enough to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a vertical strut to have a fixed height across all boxes. This can either be in the form of `\strut`, or using something like `\myvstrut` (as in the example below):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
% Normal
\fbox{$\pi$}\ \fbox{$\overline{\pi}$}\ \fbox{$di$}\ \fbox{${}^{-1}$}\ \fbox{$di,\pi$}\ \fbox{$di,\pi,{}^{-1}$} \par \medskip
% Modified
\newcommand{\myvstrut}{\vphantom{$,\pi^{-1}$}}
\fbox{\myvstrut$\pi$}\ \fbox{\myvstrut$\overline{\pi}$}\ \fbox{\myvstrut$di$}\ \fbox{\myvstrut${}^{-1}$}\ \fbox{\myvstrut$di,\pi$}\ \fbox{$di,\pi,{}^{-1}$} \par \medskip
% \strut-ed
\fbox{\strut$\pi$}\ \fbox{\strut$\overline{\pi}$}\ \fbox{\strut$di$}\ \fbox{\strut${}^{-1}$}\ \fbox{\strut$di,\pi$}\ \fbox{\strut$di,\pi,{}^{-1}$} \par \medskip
% \mathstrut-ed
\fbox{$\mathstrut\pi$}\ \fbox{$\mathstrut\overline{\pi}$}\ \fbox{$\mathstrut di$}\ \fbox{$\mathstrut{}^{-1}$}\ \fbox{$\mathstrut di,\pi$}\ \fbox{$\mathstrut di,\pi,{}^{-1}$}
\end{document}
```

`\strut` (third row) sets a vertical rule of zero width and a vertical length of `\baselineskip`, 70% in terms of height and 30% in terms of depth. This might stretch a little too low/heigh, depending on the contents of your boxes. To that end, `\mathstrut` (fourth row) is perhaps more suited since it has the height/depth of a parenthesis (`\vphantom(`). However, it's still not 100% equal across all combinations of your boxed contents. In general a `\vphantom` (second row) that includes your tallest/deepest elements works in maintaining a consistent height/depth across varying items.